# Running Powershell script from a msbuild .proj file gives System.OutOfMemoryException for large XML files

Tags: xml, powershell, msbuild, xmlreader, proj

I've created a powershell script which loads some big (50MB+) XML files and retrieves some values from it. It works fine as a standalone script (but slow).

When I call .ps1 from msbuild proj file, it starts normally but then dies on loading that big XML file with System.OutOfMemoryException exception.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" Test.proj
```

Powershell 4.0

My workaround is to use XMLReader instead of XMLDocument so it does sequential reading, works way faster and does not die under MSBUILD.

Although I am happy with my workaround, I still wonder why I have that memory limitations when executing ps1 from msbuild task?

Is it 32-bit version of MSBUILD to blame? Or it's by design?

Answer (score 1):

#### You could try to [increase PowerShell memory limit](http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2014/03/out-of-memory-exception-in-powershell/):

> When running scripts in a large environment, you could run into an
>   exception in PowerShell telling you it’s out of memory.
>
> [image: PS-OutOfMemory]
>
> To get the value of the amount of memory available per shell, run the
>   following command:
>
> [image: PS-GetMaxMemoryPerShellMB]
>
> The PowerShell `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` quota defaults to only 150MB in v1
>   and v2, and 1024MB in v3. But even under PowerShell 3.0 large objects
>   can consume large amounts of memory.
>
> You can resolve the ‘out of memory’ exception simply by increasing the
>   value of `MaxMemoryPerShellMB`. To accomplish this, use the following
>   command:
>
> [image: PS-SetMaxMemoryPerShellMB]
>
> As shown in the screenshot above, you can run the `Get-Item` command
>   again to verify the command.
>
> Last: Restart the winrm service… and you’re done :-)

#### Removing limit completely:

> I was having memory limit issues running powershell remote commands
>   that launch java programs on that remote host. I found setting the
>   `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` to zero, effectively removes the limit and allowed
>   my program to run
>
> ```
> Set-Item .\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 0
> ```

#### Note:

> ...that this setting only affects WSMan shells and not PowerShell
>   itself. These settings are only for the remoting component of WSMan
>   calls WinRM.  They can also be configured via WinRM at an command
>   prompt.

#### References:

- [Learn How to Configure PowerShell Memory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I saw that Scripting Guy page but could not get it working. Your commands work right away though :) I'll check how much memory MSBuild gives for my script.

Comment: As a followup: when ran from MSBuild, the script shows the same 1024 memory cap. So I reset the maximum to 0. Which changes something: now there is no more OutOfMemory exception, but there is still a weird exception about invalid node inserting into the XML. While I just select a node... Again, the same standalone script runs fine.

Comment: Executing the script from 32bit Powershell gives exceptions similar to MSBuild. So I incline to think it is 32bit version of MSBuild limits the max memory for an object size to 2GB.